# Map url text to boolean parameter with MVC attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

Given the following two urls:

- /employee/list/active
- /employee/list/inactive

How do I map the active/inactive part of the url to a boolean action method parameter, active being true, inactive being false?

```
[Route("employee/list")]    
public ActionResult List(bool? active = null)
```

Comment: it's easier to use `enum` not `bool?` in your case othewise you should write custom `ModelBinder`.

Comment: Why not `/employee/list/true` and `/employee/list/false`? You cannot map "active" and "inactive" to a boolean property.

Comment: Well that's the current behaviour but it makes no sense to the user. True or false what? The enum is a good idea, I will investigate further. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The enum is a correct approach as it allows you to easily add new statuses in the future :

```
[Route("employee/list/{status}")]
public ActionResult List(status status)
{
    ...
}

public enum status { active, inactive }
```

---

Even though, based on the single responsibility principle, I would prefer a simpler solution like this:

```
[Route("employee/list/active")]
public ActionResult ListActive()
{
    return List(true);
}

[Route("employee/list/inactive")]
public ActionResult ListInactive()
{
    return List(false);
}

public ActionResult List(status status)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I reworked it to use a string so it worked like this:

```
[Route("employee/list")]
[Route("employee/list/{active}")]
public ActionResult List(string active ="both")
{
   ///Stuff happens here
}
```

It's important to add the first, parameterless route if you need the parameter to be optional.

Update: This route works too

```
[Route("employee/list/{active='both'}")]
```