# How to use attribute routing in one action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I need to routing to one action by attribute routing in mvc5 .
My action :

```
  [Route("bus/{DepProvince}{From}/{DesProvince}-{To}/{DepartureDate}/{IsForeign}")]
        public ActionResult Index(int? DepProvince, int? From/*City*/, int? DesProvince, int? To/*City*/, string DepartureDate, bool? IsForeign){}
```

Query string is :

```
/Bus?DepProvince=11000000&From=11321006&RetProvince  =31000000&To=31310000&DepartureDate=1396%2F09%2F07  &IsForeign=False
```

I need to access to this action by this url :

```
/Bus/11000000-11321006/31000000-31310000/13960907/0
```

I use this code in Routconfig.cs :

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
                     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                      //---------------------BusRoute---------------------------
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BusRoute",
            url: "{*permalink}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Bus", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { permalink = new BusConstraint() },
            namespaces: new[] { "TravelEnterProject.Controllers" }
            );
```

When Run app get error :
[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem  :

```
[Route("bus")]
[Route("bus/index")]

    [Route("bus/{From:int}/{To:int}/{Date:int}/{IsForeign:int:range(0,1)}/{Title}")]
                public ActionResult Index(int? From, int? To, int? Date, int? IsForeign)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces from the route template and string is the default so no need to include it.

```
[Route("bus/{From:int}-{To:int}/{DepartureDate}/{IsForeign:bool}")]
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: I delete spaces from route and add another params to route but don't solved

Comment: I change such as  
  [Route("bus/{DepProvince:int}/{From:int}/{DesProvince:int}/{To:int}/{DepartureDate}/{IsForeign}")]   and solved

Comment: For {IsForeign:bool}  get error . How to specific bool type for attributes?

Comment: @programmer138200 for your answer on how to use boolean, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412425/map-url-text-to-boolean-parameter-with-mvc-attribute-routing), the first answer of using enums.

Comment: I  change type of boolean param to int and  Now I have  another problem that when go to previous urls's such as /bus/index or /bus  get error that    The resource cannot be found.